# Nginx location match - String contains

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

In nginx conf am trying to match the URL which contains a specific string.
URL be like

```
domain/./.?id=<script>

domain/./.?id=%3Cscript%3E

domain/./.?id=%3C%2Cscript%3E
```

I need to match the word **script** and should return 403.

```
location ~* (?:script){
     return 403;
}
```

I tried some more of the regex in https://nginx.viraptor.info/ but none of it's working.

Comment: `location` doesn't look into query strings.

Comment: @revo Is there any alternative solution without using if condition inside the location?

Comment: You're pretty much stuck with an `if` statement. But the `return 403` is [perfectly safe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). For example: `if ($arg_id = "script") { return 403; }`